# Reading in Data into SAS using 'Where' function

Tags: sas, data-manipulation, data-management

For some reason I'm not being able to read in the data properly. I want to be able to read in a large data set but within only specific dates such as Jan 2004 to FEB 2004. My Code is the following:

```
DATA Work.sales_fact;
SET Work.sales_fact_subset;
WHERE '01JAN2004'd <= Order_Date <= '14FEB2004'd;
RUN;

PROC PRINT;
RUN;
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You're missing an AND...
WHERE '01JAN2004'd <= Order_Date AND Order_Date <= '14FEB2004'd;

Comment: Syntax looks fine to me. What makes you think something is wrong? Are you getting an error message? Returning the wrong number of records?  Check that Order_Date is a numeric date variable. This step is reading sales_fact_subset. Do you mean to read sales_fact instead?

Comment: It just doesnt seem to read in the data accordingly. I get the entire dataset instead of the subset from those dates im asking for. @ramb still doesnt work.

Comment: You're right, I'm assamed I didnt know that this syntax would work. I'll leave an example as an answer using a SASHelp Dataset.

Comment: What values do you see for order_date from `proc means data=sales_fact_subset min mean max; var Order_Date; run;`  ?    And again, are you sure you intend to read sales_fact_subset or do you intend to read sales_fact?

Comment: @Quentin, if you want, you can answer this with an example like mine and your suggestions. I'll then delete my answer if you do.

Comment: I'm going to guess that your date isn't actually a SAS date, if you're reading from a database such as SQL it's probably a datetime variable instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have `DATA` and `SET` switched.  `DATA` is what you want to create.  `SET` is where the data is coming from.

```
DATA Work.sales_fact_subset ;
SET Work.sales_fact;
WHERE '01JAN2004'd <= Order_Date <= '14FEB2004'd;
RUN;

PROC PRINT data=Work.sales_fact_subset;
RUN;
```

Comment: Thank you sir, you are a genius. I cant believe I didnt get that, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of this working..
Please check your dataset.

```
data want;
set sashelp.rent;
where "01feb1999"d <= date <= "02feb2003"d;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table names and date structure is correct, your query is correct. Here is a sample of what I did with the correct result set.

```
 data inputs;
       input Date1 date9. ;
       Format date1 date9.;
       cards;
01JAN2004 
02FEB2004
03MAR2004
04JUN2004
05JUL2004 
    ;



DATA inputss;
SET inputs;
WHERE '01JAN2004'd <= Date1 <= '14FEB2004'd;
RUN;

PROC PRINT;
RUN;
```

[image]